# Are Silverlight better for non-techy people type audience?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I want to make a Recipe submisison system in Silverlight. But the problem is that whole audience are non-tech savvy. Very few of them are rarely have Abobe Flash. And if I put Silverlight Required then they have a new problem first that what is silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user doesn't have to be technically savvy to use a Silverlight application. If they do not have the Silverlight plugin then the default link supplied with the `<object>` tag in the page gives them a very easy way to install it - no skills required.

For instance, if you uninstall Silverlight from your machine and then visit http://silverlight.net you will see what i mean.